# Failure to start slate md middleman server

Tags: markdown, bundle, apple-m1, slate

When trying to setup a slate md server on my m1 mac, i am running into this error

```
bundler: failed to load command: middleman (/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/middleman)
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.rb:1:in `require': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.bundle' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.bundle (LoadError)
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/redcarpet-3.5.1/lib/redcarpet.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/middleman-core-4.4.3/lib/middleman-core/load_paths.rb:35:in `setup_bundler'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/middleman-core-4.4.3/lib/middleman-core/load_paths.rb:15:in `setup_load_paths'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.4.3/bin/middleman:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/middleman:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/middleman:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:474:in `exec'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:128:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.22/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.6_1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

from what it looks like, the redcarpet markdown parser cannot run on my m1 mac. I've tried to run my terminal under rosetta2. I've also tried using the `arch -arm64` command when running `bundle exec middleman server`. I was following the user guide on the slate wiki page. Btw using the same process i was able to run the server on a non-m1 mac, i just don't have access to that machine anymore. Can anyone make suggestions on what to do to remedy this issue? Is there a version of redcarpet that works with m1 architecture?